# Base Plotting Systems : legend color

Tags: r, plot

Im trying to put a legend label on my plot, but for some reason, the color is not appearing. Here's how it looks:

```
plot(x=plot1$t,y=plot1$q,col ="red",xlab = 't',ylab = 'q(t)',pch =20,cex=0.5,type = 'p')    
points(x=plot2$t,y=plot2$q,pch=20,col = "blue",cex=0.1)
points(x=plot3$t,y=plot3$q,pch =20, col = "purple",cex=0.1)
legend("topleft",legend=c("\u0394 t = 0.1", "\u0394 t = 0.01", "\u0394 t = 0.001"),col = c("red","blue","purple"))
```

Here's how the plot looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The name of the argument is not `col`. You need

```
text.col = c("red","blue","purple")
```